# Error in mysql query in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a mysql query in my php strict where I have to insert the current date in a column, but when running, I am confronted with this error:

> Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '22:42:06 WHERE RequestorID = 1 AND RequesteeID = 5 AND StoryID = 16' at line 1

Here is the part of my code that is causing this issue:

```
$usrID = 5;
//The user that accepts
$rqstorID = 1;
//This requestor
$stryID = 16;
//The story ID
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Beirut');
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$sql1 = "UPDATE clearance SET ClearanceDate= $date WHERE RequestorID = $rqstorID AND RequesteeID = $usrID AND StoryID = $stryID";
//The mysql query causing the error
```

I can't seem to find the cause of this error as I checked the column names thoroughly and just for clarification ClearanceDate is of type datetime. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Thank you for the helpful input from you all and for directing me to the similar question. I just put the $date variable in single quotes and it worked like a charm.

Comment: ClearanceDate = ".$date." WHERE

Comment: @clearshot66 - that shouldn't matter, as he is using double-quotes, rather than single-quotes. With double-quotes, PHP will automatically evaluate any variables contained within the string.

Comment: Ever heard about [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)?

Comment: Queries still require quoted values if they are strings @ObsidianAge

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)***. Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: Quick and dirty fix is to enclose `$date` in apostrophes. Proper fix is to use prepared statements.

Comment: If you post an answer without prepared statements [you may want to consider this before posting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344703/). Additionally [a more valuable answer comes from showing the OP the right method](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290789/1011527).

Comment: As I stated in my answer getting downvoted...

Comment: @AlonEitan  Before you start freaking out "SQL injection" you have to ask yourself what is the **source** of the parameters used in the SQL statement . if the case is like the question only `$date` variable come from this statement `date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` you can concatenate it's value to the SQL statement safely,  unless the php core function `date()` has been tampered with

Comment: @Accountantم If the user is executing queries the way they do in this example I can assume that it's the same in other places. I never run queries like the this - Not even if I can control the source. It's just not a good practice to begin with. (Side note - I doubt that it's always `$usrID = 5;` and `$rqstorID = 1;` - It look like a simplified example of their real code)

Comment: Oh, and they could just update rhe field to `NOW()` if you think about it ;)